# Change the header cell background color

Tags: html, css

I want to set the background color of table header cell on the click of cell .

Below is the css by which I am setting the background of table header cell .

```css
#tblid > thead > tr > th {
    color: #515151;
    background: #b6e9fc;
}
```

Now, on click of header cell when I am setting different color then  new color is not appearing on UI instead original background hides the new background color .I can see the new color in developer tool if we remove the original background color from the above css.

Could you please suggest some solution for this problem .I don't  want to remove the background color first and then set the new because If I remove the original background then complete header row will lost the background.Please suggest some better way to achieve this .

Thanks .

Comment: Please share your JS and HTML - or maybe make a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this through css only by applying the active selector. I am able to set the background color of `th` cell after clicking on header cell.

```css
#tblid > thead > tr > th:active {
        color: #515151;
        background: #86dafa;
 }
```

```html
<table id="tblid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Cell</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```